# Appropriateness of Poisson distribution for low number of trials with the probability = 0.5 of success

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm working on the following problem from Ross "A First Course in Probability" (9th edition):

> People enter a gambling casino at a rate of 1 every 2 minutes. (a)
> What is the probability that no one enters between 12:00 and 12:05?
> (b) What is the probability that at least 4 people enter the casino
> during that time?

(problem 63, chapter 4, page 178)

The official solution manual approaches the problem as a Poisson process, but why is it appropriate? I feel like for a small number of trials (n = 5) and high probability (p = 0.5) the Binomial distribution would be more fit. The answer is quite different depending on what distribution we use:

Binomial(n = 5, p=0.5): $ P(X=0) = 0.03125; P(X \geq 4) = 0.1875 $

Poisson($\lambda = 2.5$): $ P(X = 0) = 0.082; P(X \geq 4) = 0.242 $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not just five trials; it's infinitely many trials with an infinitely small probability of success on each trial. Or, if you like, one can approximate it by dividing the dividing every minute into $10\,000$ small intervals, each with probability $1/20\,000$ of someone entering the casino, so it's $\operatorname{Binomial}(2.5\times10\,000,\,\,\, 1/20\,000).$ And an even closer approximation to the Poisson distribution (but not very much closer since you're extremely close already) is achieved by dividing each minute into $100\,000$ parts, each with probability $1/200\,000$ of a customer entering.